# angular and ui-router - opening a detail page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm sure ui-router is very useful when a site gets complex, but man is it indecipherable on a simple site.

I've got a table with a bunch of records on a summary page called **/records/**. (not concerned about how this page was built - it's built with ng-grid)

I want to click on record 102 and have it open **/records/102** where I will  use the id to show deets of 102.

This plunker is never going to work, but I've tried to put the basics in:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qfEaMM8Ihgg8gCUAMHbE?p=catalogue

```
enter code here
```

This: {{row.entity['id']}} *does* give me the record ID I'm looking for - I've got that working. It's a matter of how I get it to routes.js where it says  url: '/records/:recId' and then how I get it to appear in the URL when it goes to the new page.

How do I do that?

(P.S. 'Submit Error: links to Plunker must be accompanied by code'. What??)

Comment: I take that you want to have `<a href="/records/{{row.entity['id']}}" ...>` ?

Comment: Yes. And once on that page, how do I grab that parameter?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. Updated the plunker, though it's still far too simple to work. But the guts is this:

summary-page html:
`<a ui-sref="details({ id:row.entity['id']})">`

routes.js:
`url: '/details/:id'`

details controller:
`$scope.id = $state.params.id;`

details html
`<span>Record# {{id}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to `/records/102` you just use a normal html anchor like this:

```
<a href="/records/{{row.entity['id']}}" ...>
```

Yo get the value out in your `RecordsController` you need to use the `$routeParams` service, inject it and use it like this:

```
$scope.recordId = $routeParams.recId;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem very ui-router-like.